# Asp Core Identity, How to get userId after login?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have 2 controllers named : `AdminProfileController` And `UserProfileController`. I want get userId and user role directly after logged in because i want user go to `AdminProfileController` if user had `Admin Role` and go to `UserProfileController` if user had `User Role`.

**My Code**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Model Erroe");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }


    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return Redirect("/AdminProfile/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/UserProfile/Index");
            }
        }
    }
```

But `User.IsInRole("Admin")` always is `false`, I also tried to get the `userId` by this code :

```
 string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
```

But it returns also null .
How can i get `userId` or `role` directly after logged in to navigate to Specified path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason you don't get get value you expect from `User.IsInRole` because this reads roles from a cookie and cookie is not yet set at the point where you use this method.

For the same reason you don't get anything out of `_userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User)`. At the point of execution `HttpContext.User` is not set yet.

At the point where you do the checks, to determine if user is in role, best thing to do is to use `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151686(v=vs.108).aspx). This methods checks the database for roles. Also to get user object you can use `UserManager.FindByNameAsync` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151639(v=vs.108).aspx) and pass `model.UserName` value there. You'll get your `ApplicationObject` instance back to you and will get your `userId` for role checking.

Answer (score 4):

I can solve it. just try it:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            string existingRole = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result.Single();

            //string userid = user.id;
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl,existingRole);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Model Erroe");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}





private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl,string roleName)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        if (roleName == "Admin")
        {
            return Redirect("/Admin/User");
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("/User/UserProfile");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Good start and idea, but poor implementation. You will have an exception if user has no roles or more than one. Also you should use `await _userManager.GetRolesAsync` instead of using `.Result` - that will avoid possible deadlocks.

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Take the time to explain what the code is doing.